Finding nested `vendor` folder

I'm searching for a specific nested folder.
This nested folder is in the form of **/**/vendor/**/**/vendor
I would like to find and delete this 2nd vendor

Any ideas?

If the folder can be at any depth:

Enable the ** feature:
$ shopt -s globstar


Find the folder:
$ echo **/vendor/**/vendor

$ ls -ld **/vendor/**/vendor


Remove the folder:
$ rmdir **/vendor/**/vendor

(or rm -rvf if it's non-empty)


If the folder is always at a specific depth, you can achieve the same using regular *.

thanks, is echo **/vendor/**/vendor an alternative to ls ...? it is stuck there at the moment

Wildcard expansion is done by the shell, not by the command. I am guessing it's stuck because Bash is still digging through your subfolders trying to expand the wildcard, and will proceed to run the command (doesn't matter which command really) once it's done. There are likely faster ways to do it (e.g. a 'find' chained to an 'xargs find') but this is what came to mind first.

I meant, you have 2 commands under point 2, are they equivalent? Meaning, just run 1? or must I run both? Anyway I only ran the ls ... and got a list of results

@bilogic The echo command simply prints the expanded directory (or file) name, the ls -ld command will additionally show some details like permissions, owner, size, ... because of the -l option. You only need one, depending on what information you want to see. You could also copy&paste the printed path to the rmdir command to avoid that the shell has to repeat the possibly slow recursive search.
